# Using CASE Statement when using two different statement if the condition is true

Tags: php, mysql

1. I need to display the data retrieving from table Market wise. And for each Market, Number of Orders and No of Items can be calculated and displayed. I have only one column namely market, but i need to display market in horizontal manner .

I have tried creating Temporary Table to achieve this. Anyhow i got the result, but is not accurate.

```
    $MarketQry="SELECT DISTINCT `Market` FROM `orders`";
    $MarketResult=mysql_query($MarketQry,$con);
    $OrdersQry="";
    while($mvalue=mysql_fetch_array($MarketResult))
    {
        $OrdersQry.="CASE WHEN `Market`='".$mvalue['Market']."' THEN SUM(`Count`) ELSE 0 END AS `".$mvalue['Market']." -Number of Orders`, CASE WHEN `Market`='".$mvalue['Market']."' THEN SUM(`Records`) ELSE 0 END AS `".$mvalue['Market']." -Number of Order Line Items`,";              
    }

$createqry="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp_order_market` AS 
        SELECT ".$OrdersQry."`OrderDate` FROM 
        (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `OrderID`) AS `Count`,COUNT(`OrderID`) AS `Records`,`OrderDate`,`Market` 
        FROM `orders` 
        WHERE (`OrderDate` BETWEEN '$StartDate' AND '$EndDate')  
        GROUP BY `OrderDate`) 
        ) AS `dummy` GROUP BY `OrderDate` ORDER BY `OrderDate` DESC";

echo $createqry."<br /><br />"; 

$resQry=mysql_query($createqry,$con) or die(mysql_error($con));

$selectqry="SELECT * FROM `temp_order_market`";
```

2. Whatever i am getting the result is not accurate. Since If i get the result for individual market i am getting the exact result. The following is the query i am using for getting result for individual market.

   ```
   SELECT SUM(`Count`) AS `Orders`,SUM(`Records`) AS `Records`,`OrderDate` FROM 
               (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `OrderID`) AS `Count`,COUNT(`OrderID`) AS `Records`,`OrderDate` 
               FROM `orders` 
               WHERE (`OrderDate` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31') AND `Market`='$MarketName' 
               GROUP BY `OrderDate`)) AS `dummy` GROUP BY `OrderDate` ORDER BY `OrderDate` DESC";
   ```

Now my question is:

1. Can we do this other than this method/Is this possible to achieve the method that i am using?
2. I doubt the CASE Statement of the query I've written.

Please share your thoughts. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding SUM() to the $OrderQry, it is now working fine.

## **OLD**

```
$OrdersQry.="CASE WHEN `Market`='".$mvalue['Market']."' THEN SUM(`Count`) ELSE 0 END AS `".$mvalue['Market']." -Number of Orders`, CASE WHEN `Market`='".$mvalue['Market']."' THEN SUM(`Records`) ELSE 0 END AS `".$mvalue['Market']." -Number of Order Line Items`,";
```

## **Replaced To**

```
$OrdersQry.="SUM(CASE WHEN `Market`='".$mvalue['Market']."' THEN SUM(`Count`) ELSE 0 END) AS `".$mvalue['Market']." -Number of Orders`, SUM(CASE WHEN `Market`='".$mvalue['Market']."' THEN SUM(`Records`) ELSE 0 END) AS `".$mvalue['Market']." -Number of Order Line Items`,";
```